# SQL Developer: Uploading date format

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.03.  I am trying to upload an Excel file to an Oracle data table.  I am getting an error for the date.  The column in the database is a timestamp and I don't know what to put into the date format of the 'Data Load Wizard'.  If I use the following format I get 'Insert failed for row 1 GDK-05016: duplicate month found.

dd-mom-yy hh.mm.ss

Any idea what the correct format should be?

In the db, the date column looks like this: 01-MAY-12 01.16.50.000000000PM

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When I run the following query (select to_timestamp('40604.0', 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss') from dual), I get the following error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for minutes is `mi` not `mm`

(I assume `mom` is just a typo and is actually reading `mon`)

For a full list of all supported format models, please see the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA

Comment: When I run the following query (select to_timestamp('40604.0', 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss') from dual), I get the following error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Comment: @JeremyF. that's because `'40604.0'` does not match the format mask you have specified. It's missing the dashes as required by `dd-mon-yy` and does not include hours, minutes and seconds as required by `hh.mi.ss`. Additionally `mon` requires a month **name** not two digits. This is all explained in the link I posted

Answer (score 0):

The Excel "zero" date is January 0 (yes, zero), 1900.  Since Oracle can't handle a "zero" day in a month you need to subtract 1 from the Excel value; thus the following should get you close to what you want:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_DATE('01-JAN-1900 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP) +
           NUMTODSINTERVAL(41017.6361109954 - 1, 'DAY')
  FROM DUAL
```

As far as "how to import it" goes, there's no Oracle date format that I'm aware of to do this.  The easiest thing would be to import the value into a NUMBER column and then run a script to do the date conversion.

Share and enjoy.